# Valid SSL certificate for Firefox?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, ssl, ssl-certificate

I really need help here.

I'm not into SSL. I usually connect through xhr from an http-Site to an http-Site which works fine via CORS.

But now I need to do it via https->https. So I enabled the "FreeSSL" option the hoster provider. I *think* it is somehow certified by Symantec oder GeoTrust but I have my doubt about it.

Opening the REST-resource directly via Firefox, all is fine and the certificate is trusted, since it is a get request.

An AJAX-GET-request to the REST-resource also works fine.

But a AJAX-POST-request fails.

Could someone please check whether the certificate of the following site should be fine with using it in AJAX-requests in Firefox??

https://tempapi.kanubox.de/kanubox/v1/activities

That would help me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Certificate validation does not depend if the request is GET or POST and apart from that the certificate is valid.

But if these requests are possible as cross origin XHR depend on the details of the request and if there are any CORS headers set by the server. Details of the request are unknown and CORS headers are not set by the target URL so my guess is that this is unrelated to HTTP vs. HTTPS but is instead a CORS issue. Looking at the browser console (i.e. developer tools in the browser) will probably help you to find out more what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, I know. But CORS worked for HTTP/GET HTTP/POST HTTPS/GET. The issue was, that for some reason, Firefox does not set the CONTENT-LENGTH field for HTTPS/POST and (!) CONTENT-TYPE='application/json'. So the Webserver responded the CORS preflight with a 411 "Length required" which does not deliver the CORS headers. CONTENT-TYPE='application/x-www-form-urlencoded' works fine! Who is the bad guy here? Firefox or the webserver?

Comment: @ChrisPillen: If Firefox neither sets content-length nor uses transfer-encoding chunked in a POST request then this would be a bug in Firefox because some kind of length information are required with POST. Do you have (minimal) code to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: So weird: See this codepen: http://codepen.io/chrispillen/pen/dXBZkv. Uncomment the combinations that work and that don't to test them (FF 47.0)